# Overlay image on div

Tags: html, css, r, shiny, shinydashboard

I want to set image overlay a div. I want to get this :
[image]

I used `left` and `top` for image position but it doesnt work and I dont get the excepted result. This is what I did :

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    ### i use div to integrate image here ###
    div(
      img(src = "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61Jigwd1kKL._AC_SL1500_.jpg", 
            style = "left: 16px; width: 10%; border-radius: 50%; top: -60px;")
      ),
    div(id = "id", style = "width: 500px; max-width: 100%; margin: 0 auto; padding: 20px;",
        wellPanel(
          tags$h2("my title", class = "text-center"),
          div(actionButton("btn1", "click here"))
          )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) { }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

but i get this :
[image]

Some help would be appreciated

Comment: position:relative to parent div

Comment: as termaniafif said, plain HTML example with img and h2 inside the same container: `<div id="id" style="width: 500px; max-width: 100%; margin: 5em auto; padding: 20px;position:relative;border:solid;">
    <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61Jigwd1kKL._AC_SL1500_.jpg" style="left: -16px; width: 10%; border-radius: 50%; top: -30px;position:absolute">
    <h2 class="text-center">my title</h2><button> click here</button>
  </div>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use position: relative on the parent and position: absolute on the child.

```css
div {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: lightcoral;
  margin: auto;
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  left: -15px;
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200');
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason why your css didn't seem to work is because the divs have the wrong `position` setting.

There are five position settings: static, relative, absolute, fixed, sticky.

All elements are `position:static` by default, and `top` / `left` / `z-index` / etc do not work with static elements.

> There are a few things that I generally change on every website project I do, so I add something like this to the top of every CSS page:
>
> `* {position:relative; box-sizing:border-box; margin:0; padding:0; }`
>
> This is called a [CSS Reset](https://dev.to/hankchizljaw/a-modern-css-reset-6p3), and many people have devised more complicated ones (as web standards evolve, CSS Resets also get adjusted).

In your question code, the one to understand is `position:absolute` and the difference between `position: absolute` and `position: relative`.

Here's [a good description](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/). The most important sentence in the article is this one: **Remember that these values will be relative to the next parent element with relative (or absolute) positioning.** In other words, if you specify `position:absolute; top:0; left:0;` somewhere but forget that all other divs on the page are still at the default (`position:static`), your absolute div could jump to the top of the page and be `top:0; left:0;` off the body! Generally, you want to make sure the parent div (container) is not still `position: static`.

I won't do a demo since Lundstromski's answer has done a great job with that.